# Can i use only one Firebase Project for many white-labeled apps? What is the best practice?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, label, white-framework

I have a Flutter white labeled project, i want to use only the Firebase Auth on login module of all differents apps i'll generate, can i make it with only one Firebase Project and work with the UID response on the backend after the login completes? What's the best practice?

Comment: Yes you can connect more than one app. But in this case if someone try sign up your both app maybe there will be problem because existing. But i am sure if you want use same database to all apps you can do. Also if you get the code block for register from the firebase docs there is an emailexistingornot method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The recommended practice is to use a project only for single family of apps, with a single set of users. So an example of this would be to have the iOS, Android, and web versions of your app, and maybe an administrative back-end you have for that same app, and then maybe pro versions for all platforms too.

White labeling the same app for many customers should be done with a separate project for each of those customers. Otherwise you'll quickly run into limitations, such as the number of API keys you can create in a single project.